# how to define an object with optional props from an union type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I want to use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to define the type of the following type:

Examples:

```js
    const k0: Keyed = {};    // ok, empty
    const k1: Keyed = { year: 1, month: 2, week: 3 };    // ok
    const k2: Keyed = { year: 1 };    // ok, partial
    const k3: Keyed = { hour: 1 };    // wrong! hour is not in 'year' | 'month' | 'week'
    const k4: Keyed = { year: undefined }; // wrong, I want a number, not an undefined
```

I tried with the following:

```js
    type Keyed = {
        [key in 'year' | 'month' | 'week']: number;
    };
```

but `const k2: Keyed = { year: 1 }` fails with the error `Type '{ year: number; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Keyed': month, week`

Then I tried with the following to allow Keyed variables that don't have every key

```js
    type Keyed = {
        [key in 'year' | 'month' | 'week']?: number;
    };
```

But then the following `const d: Keyed = { year: undefined };` is reported ok, with all the correspondent 'xxx may be undefined` messages

I want to define that the keys of `Keyed` must be one of `'year' | 'month' | 'week'`, without neccesarily having all the properties defined, and that the value should be a number (not null nor undefined).

It seems like a really simple case but I can't find the way to achieve it.

---

I noticed that a similar problem arises with explicit properties. If I have:

```js
  type T = {
    name?: string
  }
```

All these are valid:

```
  const t1: T = {name: 'sas'}
  const t2: T = {name: undefined}
  const t3: T = {}
```

I'd like the 'name' property to be optional (that is, it can be missing), but if it is present I want it to be a string, not undefined.

---

for reference: the solution wa to set the [exactOptionalPropertyTypes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exactOptionalPropertyTypes) option in the tsconfig.json file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

turn on `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` in your `tsconfig.json` (you allow `{}` type, I think it's ok)

Comment: I updated the question, because `{}` is indeed a valid value in my case. I want to define optional props, but if they are present I want them to be `number`, not `undefined`

Comment: @opensas go with option 1 (and your second attempt as mentioned in the question), enable `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` in your tsconfig. It will do the job (`{}` will be valid but `{foo: undefined}` won't be). Also, you need ts4.4+ for that.

Comment: Yes, I realized about it, I was just reading the doc at https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exactOptionalPropertyTypes before accepting your answer

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to activate this setting for a specific portion of code (or for a file)?
I activated it on a fairly large project and I get far too many errors, even realted to libs which I don't control